# How to bulk insert generic source array into arbitrary SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, generics

My application uses Entity Framework. Most days I feel fine about that, but I have trouble when I need to do bulk insertions. I've yet to find a way for EF to do these quickly. As such, I need a solution that goes outside of EF to do the updates.

I want a method that takes a connection string, destination table name, and a generic array of source data, and performs the bulk insertions. Moreover, I'd like it to map the properties of the source data to the specific table fields, ideally without requiring attributes in the source object to designate the table field.

Thus, for this object:

```
public class Customer
{
    //property populated & used only in memory
    public string TempProperty { get; set; }

    //properties saved in the database
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    //various methods, constructors, etc.
}
```

I should be able to provide the table name `Data.Customer`, and the method should map `Customer.Name -> Data.Customers.Name`, `Customer.Address -> Data.Customers.Address`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was surprised I couldn't find the code for something like this anywhere. Maybe this isn't the best approach to the problem? That possibility notwithstanding, here's the solution I came up with.

My starting outline was something like this:

1. Use the destination table and source object type to create mapping object using reflection.
2. Iterate through the source objects, applying the mapper, to generate the insertion data.
3. Insert the data into the destination table using the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` object.

When I see an outline like this, I try to rephrase it in terms of data types, because really all I'm doing is translating my input (`T[]`) into something that `SqlBulkCopy` will accept. But to do this, I need to decide on how to map fields.

Here's what I settled on:

```
var mapper = new List<Tuple<string, Func<object, string, object>>>();
```

I chose this to represent a table that looks like this:

```
+------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Field Name |               Mapping Function               |
+------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Name       | Customer.Name -> Data.Customers.Name         |
| Address    | Customer.Address -> Data.Customers.Address   |
| Age        | Customer.Age -> Data.Customers.Age           |
| Comments   | Customer.Comments -> Data.Customers.Comments |
+------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The fact that it's a list represents the rows. That leaves us with 
`Tuple<string, Func<object, string, object>>`. This creates a sort of Dictionary (but indexed) where a given string (the field name) is mapped to a function that, when given a source object `T` and a source field (e.g. `Address`), will retrieve the appropriate value. If no corresponding property is found for a table field, we'll just return null.

After validating that the input values are valid (connection valid, table exists, etc.), we'll create our mapping object:

```
//get all the column names for the table to build mapping object
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM {foundTableName}", conn);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

//build mapping object by iterating through rows and verifying that there is a match in the table
var mapper = new List<Tuple<string, Func<object, string, object>>>();
foreach (DataRow col in reader.GetSchemaTable().Rows)
{
    //get column information
    string columnName = col.Field<string>("ColumnName");
    PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(columnName);
    Func<object, string, object> map;
    if (property == null)
    {
        //check if it's nullable and exit if not
        bool nullable = col.Field<bool>("Is_Nullable");
        if (!nullable)
            return $"No corresponding property found for Non-nullable field '{columnName}'.";

        //if it's nullable, create mapping function
        map = new Func<object, string, object>((a, b) => null);
    }
    else
        map = new Func<object, string, object>((src, fld) => typeof(T).GetProperty(fld).GetValue(src));

    //add mapping object
    mapper.Add(new Tuple<string, Func<object, string, object>>(columnName, map));
}
```

The `SqlBulkCopy` object accepts `DataRow[]` as an input, so from here we can simply create template `DataRow` objects from the destination table and fill them from our mapper:

```
//get all the data
int dataCount = sourceData.Count();
var rows = new DataRow[dataCount];
DataTable destTableDT = new DataTable();
destTableDT.Load(reader);
for (int x = 0; x < dataCount; x++)
{
    var dataRow = destTableDT.NewRow();
    dataRow.ItemArray = mapper.Select(m => m.Item2.Invoke(sourceData[x], m.Item1))
                              .ToArray();
    rows[x] = dataRow;
}
```

Then finish it out by writing the data:

```
  //set up the bulk copy connection
  SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock | 
                                          SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction, null);
  sbc.DestinationTableName = foundTableName;
  sbc.BatchSize = BATCH_SIZE;
  sbc.WriteToServer(rows);
```

And that's it! Works like a charm, and ran too fast for me to bother benchmarking (EF was taking several minutes to run these imports).

I should note that I left out a lot of my error checking code and will probably be adding more. However, if you'd like to see my class in its entirety, here it is:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Data.Common;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Reflection;

  namespace DatabaseUtilities
  {
      public static class RapidDataTools
      {
          const int SCHEMA_SCHEMA_NAME = 1;
          const int SCHEMA_TABLE_NAME = 2;
          const int BATCH_SIZE = 1000;

          /// <summary>
          /// Imports an array of data into a specified table. It does so by mapping object properties
          /// to table columns. Only properties with the same name as the column name will be copied;
          /// other columns will be left null. Non-nullable columns with no corresponding property will
          /// throw an error.
          /// </summary>
          /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
          /// <param name="destTableName">Qualified table name (e.g. Admin.Table)</param>
          /// <param name="sourceData"></param>
          /// <returns></returns>
          public static string Import<T>(string connectionString, string destTableName, T[] sourceData)
          {
              //get destination table qualified name
              string[] tableParts = destTableName.Split('.');
              if (tableParts.Count() != 2) return $"Invalid or unqualified destination table name: {destTableName}.";
              string destSchema = tableParts[0];
              string destTable = tableParts[1];

              //create the database connection
              SqlConnection conn = GetConnection(connectionString);
              if (conn == null) return "Invalid connection string.";

              //establish connection
              try { conn.Open(); }
              catch { return "Could not connect to database using provided connection string."; }

              //make sure the requested table exists
              string foundTableName = string.Empty;
              foreach (DataRow row in conn.GetSchema("Tables").Rows)
                  if (row[SCHEMA_SCHEMA_NAME].ToString().Equals(destSchema, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                      row[SCHEMA_TABLE_NAME].ToString().Equals(destTable, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                  {
                      foundTableName = $"{row[SCHEMA_SCHEMA_NAME]}.{row[SCHEMA_TABLE_NAME]}";
                      break;
                  }
              if (foundTableName == string.Empty) return $"Specified table '{destTableName}' could not be found in table.";

              //get all the column names for the table to build mapping object
              SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM {foundTableName}", conn);
              SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

              //build mapping object by iterating through rows and verifying that there is a match in the table
              var mapper = new List<Tuple<string, Func<object, string, object>>>();
              foreach (DataRow col in reader.GetSchemaTable().Rows)
              {
                  //get column information
                  string columnName = col.Field<string>("ColumnName");
                  PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(columnName);
                  Func<object, string, object> map;
                  if (property == null)
                  {
                      //check if it's nullable and exit if not
                      bool nullable = col.Field<bool>("Is_Nullable");
                      if (!nullable)
                          return $"No corresponding property found for Non-nullable field '{columnName}'.";

                      //if it's nullable, create mapping function
                      map = new Func<object, string, object>((a, b) => null);
                  }
                  else
                      map = new Func<object, string, object>((src, fld) => typeof(T).GetProperty(fld).GetValue(src));

                  //add mapping object
                  mapper.Add(new Tuple<string, Func<object, string, object>>(columnName, map));
              }

              //get all the data
              int dataCount = sourceData.Count();
              var rows = new DataRow[dataCount];
              DataTable destTableDT = new DataTable();
              destTableDT.Load(reader);
              for (int x = 0; x < dataCount; x++)
              {
                  var dataRow = destTableDT.NewRow();
                  dataRow.ItemArray = mapper.Select(m => m.Item2.Invoke(sourceData[x], m.Item1)).ToArray();
                  rows[x] = dataRow;
              }

              //close the old connection
              conn.Close();

              //set up the bulk copy connection
              SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction, null);
              sbc.DestinationTableName = foundTableName;
              sbc.BatchSize = BATCH_SIZE;

              //establish connection
              try { conn.Open(); }
              catch { return "Failed to re-established connection to the database after reading data."; }

              //write data
              try { sbc.WriteToServer(rows); }
              catch (Exception ex) { return $"Batch write failed. Details: {ex.Message} - {ex.StackTrace}"; }

              //if we got here, everything worked!
              return string.Empty;
          }

          private static SqlConnection GetConnection(string connectionString)
          {
              DbConnectionStringBuilder csb = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
              try { csb.ConnectionString = connectionString; }
              catch { return null; }
              return new SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString);
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is basically 3 approach for performing Bulk Insert in Entity Framework

- Entity Framework Extensions *(Recommended)*
- EntityFramework.BulkInsert *(Limited and unsupported)*
- SqlBulkCopy (Complex to make it work)

The first 2 library add extension methods to the DbContext

```
using (var ctx = new EntitiesContext())
{
    ctx.BulkInsert(list);
}
```

You can learn more about this three techniques in this [article](http://entityframework.net/fastest-way-to-insert)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

Comment: Very cool! I saw this during my search, but didn't relish selling a paid extension to my employer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at NuGet package "EntityFramework.Utilities", you can add it to your project. It has features for this. You'll have to do some recoding, but this will probably benefit you in the end.

References:

> - https://www.nuget.org/packages/EFUtilities/ (package)
> - https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities (source +
>     examples)